# Is it possible to match sets in a make file?

Tags: c, makefile, pattern-matching

I have a make file that uses pattern matching to automate compilation using a rule like this:

```
%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $<
```

However in this project I have a number of source files which differ in case of their extension. Is there a way to match sets in make files like in regular expressions.

Pseudo-example:

```
%.o : %.[cC]
    gcc -c $<
```

It is not possible to simply change the case of the source files as this is used for module testing of an existing project which mixes modules from several other.

Comment: It looks like your second example is the solution. Have you tried it? It works fine with GNU Make.

Comment: It seems like make will issue a standard build command if it can't find a matching rule. If you add and echo line to the command you will see that the rule is not executed.

Comment: It works for me. Maybe it's GNU Make extension. What version of make are you using?

Comment: It works for me too (GNUMake 3.81), which baffles me. I didn't know Make had any such behavior, and I'm not sure I like it.

Comment: I'm using GNU Make 3.81 on a standard Ubuntu 10.04. As far is I know I don't have any extensions installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out that the makefile had several issues.

First the example I posted actually works as Banthar pointed out. However my problem was that my sourcefiles weren't in the root directory but in a src/ subdirectory which I had added to vpath. I honestly thought it was irrelevant to my question as I believed make would automatically scan its vpath for source files. Turns out vpath does not apply to rule checking.

To make it work do:

```
vpath = %.c src
vpath = %.C src

%o : src/%.[Cc]
    gcc -c $<
```

Next as I was working through examples of how to get it done make would sometimes build sourcefiles behind my back. If you do:

```
all : main.o
    gcc -o test main.o
```

... and not have rule to build the .o file make will build it using implicit inbuild rules. Quite confusing. It can be disabled using the -r flag.

```
make -r all
```

Third compiling .C files using gcc without any extra options will result in linker errors because gcc interprets .C files as C++ files as default. In order to compiles as C files use -x flag.

```
%.o : %.C
    gcc -x c -c %<
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option I can see is simply to link non-matching cases:

```
%.c : %.C
        ln $< $@
```

and let rule chaining do the rest.